# playing video locally within my app

Tags: android, facebook, video

Totally new to this. I am trying to create an app that plays video files stored within the app. What I mean is that it does not stream it, it plays it locally when downloaded. I know that this will increase the file size of the app.

My intention is to have multiple videos in the app. I think I worked out the menu and navigation but I need help adding the videos and then playing them for when they are needed.

Also looking for a way to link this app to a Facebook page and website and tweeter and have a way of having a live update notice, where I can let people know about events and so on.

Any help with this would be greatfull

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking to use a VideoView which takes in a URI or FilePath (file path in your case).

Slap on a MediaController for playback options.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

Comment: hi thanks for the post is their any video lesson i can view that you know off again thank you for your reply

Comment: Run a google search for a tutorial with viewview and mediacontroller? I get a bunch of youtube tutorials with those key words.